# Scheduled Follow Up activity after creating an event

Tags: civievent, civimail, civirules

We wanted to create 2 reminders after creating events within civicrm.

The first is to automatically create a follow-up activity to a particular contact after an event has been create ie pay invoice etc

The second is to automatically send an email to a particular contact X amount of days before the event date and the email to have event tokens like amount of participants etc.

I'm struggling to find ways to do this within CiviCRM or via extensions or modules like CiviRules or the Civi Rules / Civi Entity modules.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention your CMS, but if you find CiviRules cannot be coerced in to doing your bidding, then if you are on Drupal and add CiviCRM Entity in to the mix, then you can build Drupal Rules which may provide a sidestep solution.